# Readjust Pivot data using if statement

Tags: vba, excel

Currently have data for each month in a separate tab (eg. January data in Tab "January"...) Have pivot tables preformatted in last few tabs. First Tab has a drop down which has all the months. User chooses a month, VBA macro fills pivot table with data from selected month's tab.

- If "January" selected from drop down
- Then format pivot tables using "January" tab data

Any assistance in how to structure the VBA code would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: On the first tab, is the drop down a combobox or just data validation?  You will need to show some code for the people here to give you a meaningful answer, since this isn't a code writing site.   [ask]

Comment: The drop down is just a data validation

Answer (score 0):

If the data in each of the month sheets have named ranges, you could use the following code once the month is selected on the first tab:

```
Sheet("YourPivotTableSheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").changePivotcache 
ActiveWorkbook.Pivotcaches
  .create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="YourNewNamedRange", Version:=6)
```